# htaccess redirecting traffic coming from a forum to an a specific image

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, forum

I'm having this recurring problem where some users try to post an image link from my blog in a forum thread but they always used the post's url instead of the actual image link I provide in the post. 
My image is not appearing in the forum post because it's linked like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/
```

when the user should have used the image link as

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/image.jpg
```

My question is if it's possible with .htaccess to redirect this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/image.jpg
```

but only for the forum my site was linked to.

The idea is to have my image show up in the forum thread instead of the wrong url.

this is the kind of referrals I often see

```
http://www.somewebsite.com/forum/showthread.php?t=numbersxxxx
```

Thanks anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Redirect /post-title/ http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/image.jpg
```

Comment: I'm not sure I made much sense, forgive my bad English, I need to redirect from specif referrals, what I need is to display an image when someone posts in forums this link as image


`<img border="0" alt="" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/post-title/">`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.somewebsite\.com/forum/showthread\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1/image.jpg [L]
```

This will work for any "post-title". And you can add a `R` flag if you want to redirect.